# How can I make all CharField in uppercase direct in model?

Tags: django, models

I tried to use UpperCase in all my CharField, in all my Django Model.

Today I have some code in my save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in ['razao_social', 'nome_fantasia', 'cidade', 'endereco','bairro', 'uf', 'cli_parc_nomeparc', 'cli_repr_nomerepr']:
            val = getattr(self, field_name, False)
            if val:
                setattr(self, field_name, val.upper())
        super(Pessoa, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But its take some time. There`s any method to put some uppercase=True in my models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way would be to define custom model field:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass


class UpperCharField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.CharField)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_uppercase = kwargs.pop('uppercase', False)
        super(UpperCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(UpperCharField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if self.is_uppercase:
            return value.upper()

        return value
```

and use it like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    razao_social = UpperCharField(max_length=50, uppercase=True)
    # next field will not be upper-cased by default (it's the same as CharField)
    nome_fantasia = UpperCharField(max_length=50)
    # etc..
```

you also need to resolve [south migration issues](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part4.html#keyword-arguments) (if necessary), by adding this code:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [UpperCharField],
        [],
        {
            "uppercase": ["uppercase", {"default": False}],
        },
    ),
], ["^myapp\.models\.UpperCharField"])
```

(path in the last line depends on the field class localization. Please read the south docs for explanation.)

Although there's a small downside when you use shell for instance to create model object and save it in variable:

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.create(razao_social='blah')
print my_object.razao_social
```

you won't get upper-cased value. You need to retrieve the object from the database. I will update this post, when I find out how to resolve this issue as well.

Comment: Great answer, with useful links and +1 for the South info. There is one small problem though with your code: Since you're using the attribute name `is_uppercase`, the south introspection rule needs to use it. Change the middle line to: `"uppercase": ["is_uppercase", {"default" : False}],`

Answer (score 21):

Here is how to override a Django Model Field and make it **upper-case** as of `Django 1.8`.

This will:

- work by saving the upper-cased value to the database
- returns an upper-cased value in the save response.

Here's the code:

```
from django.db import models

class UpperCaseCharField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpperCaseCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = getattr(model_instance, self.attname, None)
        if value:
            value = value.upper()
            setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
            return value
        else:
            return super(UpperCaseCharField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

If you want to do this in **Django rest framework**, here's the code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UpperCaseSerializerField(serializers.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpperCaseSerializerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = super(UpperCaseSerializerField, self).to_representation(value)
        if value:
            return value.upper()
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of defining a custom field, you can also use the `RegexValidator`:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

...

my_field = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    validators=[RegexValidator('^[A-Z_]*$',
                               'Only uppercase letters and underscores allowed.')],
)
```

(see [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator))

Answer (score 2):

django 4, just override the save() method of the model

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field = self.my_field.upper()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dirty and easier solution without having to deal with migrations:

```
    char_fields = [f.name for f in self._meta.fields if isinstance(f, models.CharField) and not getattr(f, 'choices')]
    for f in char_fields:
        val = getattr(self, f, False)
        if val:
            setattr(self, f, val.upper())
    super(Cliente, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy @mariodev answer but it didn't work in python3.
This is how a solved it:

```
from django.db import models

class UpperCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_uppercase = kwargs.pop('uppercase', False)
        super(UpperCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(UpperCharField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if self.is_uppercase:
            return value.upper()

        return value

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context=None):
        if self.is_uppercase:
            return value.upper()

        return value
```